# Test in app purchases without building a release signed apk?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I had no issues with this about a year ago with having an unpublished app with published/active products. Now the method changed so I now have a published beta app with active products.

Since the published beta apk is release signed I can no longer test an app with debug signed apk. So for every test I need to build the release and load it on a device. If I don't, and use a debug apk from android studio I get the error about this app not being configured for Google play.

Works fine built in release just not debug. Surely I am doing something wrong since I can't publish a debug apk and thus cannot actually test. Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Not possible without signed apk.

Comment: @MehulJoisar Thanks for the reply but what you're saying is its not possible to test a published release apk, then how do you test local without building a release apk each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to you but should still be relevant to others having the same question/issue.

Like @mehul-joisar correctly says - it is not possible without signing the APK. You can however test and debug your implementation by signing each build. In Android studio you can change the variant you are building to "release" which will force the signing or you can have a new variant specifically for this purpose say "iap-debug" which has to sign the APK with your release signing certificate.

To speed things up, like I said you can create a new variant and disable the proguard - `minifyEnabled false` or turn it off temporarily for the release variant.

To not have to enter the keys all the time you can hard code them in your gradle, **but make sure you do not commit this to your VCS and remove after you are done testing**

Hope this helps someone.